# Performance penalty for unused view?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Suppose that I create a view in SQLite that involves joins and/or sub-selects between a few tables.  Does simply creating that view cause any performance penalty for working with the tables that the view uses?

For example, if I have tables `foo` and `bar`, and I create a view called `foo_bar`, will simply creating that view make it slower to insert into or select from `foo` and `bar`?

If it makes any difference, I am using SQLite 3.7.11 on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a view, it is just a shorthand for its query.
In other words, when you execute these statements:

```
CREATE VIEW foo_bar AS SELECT * FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar USING (foo_id);
SELECT * FROM foo_bar WHERE baz IS NULL;
```

the query is just rewritten internally to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar USING (foo_id)) WHERE baz IS NULL;
```

When you are not actually using it, a view has no effect on any other database object.